# Behavior of xparse and "token"-type argument

Tags: macros, xparse

Please consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\f}{tx}{\IfBooleanTF{#1}{true}{false}}

\begin{document}
\f{x}

\f[x]

\f x
\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:

```
falsex
false[x]
true
```

Which isn't what I expected. I expected that one of the first two would print "true", and the last one to print "false x". What is happening here? Is this the intended behavior?

Follow-up question: is there a way to get the behavior, ie. an argument that gives False when absent, and True when present?

Comment: The argument specifier `tx` means that an `x` just after `\f` sets the internal boolean to true; otherwise the boolean is set to false. In the first and second calls the `x` doesn't *directly* follow `\f`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the intended behaviour, and is because there is a difference between an argument which happens to contain a token and using a token directly. When TeX reads

```
\foo x
```

the very next thing after `\foo` is `x`. On the other hand, with

```
\foo{x}
```

the next thing after `\foo` is a `{`, while in

```
\foo[x]
```

it is a `[`. There are some technical differences between `\foo{x}` and `\foo[x]` (as one is involves a TeX group while the other is probably a LaTeX-like optional argument and will be handled using delimited macros). However, from the point of view of this question that does not matter: all that is important is that there are 'extra' tokens. The `t` specifier is purely about the next token, not what might happen *inside* other arguments.

Comment: I see, thanks. Follow-up question: would you know how to get the behavior I intended?

Comment: @nik You are checking the nature of three _different_ arguments: doable but I think far from sensible. For example, what happens about `\foo{y}` or `\foo[y]`?

Comment: I'm fine if only one of the two `\f[x]` or `\f{x}` works. I'm basing my question on constructions such as `\ar[d]` from the xymatrix package, for example.