# Change behavior of seeking argument? Observing space

Tags: macros, xparse

According to item 0.2 of the `xparse` documentation: "TEX will find the first argument after a function name irrespective of any intervening
spaces." Examples are provided, which I understand.

I am trying to create a simple macro that has no mandatory argument, but one optional argument. The text in the optional argument will be ignored. It is a non-printing memo to myself. Like this:

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand \printfive {O{}} {5}
```

Then, in the document body:

```
Two plus three make \printfive.
Two plus three make \printfive[last time I counted fingers].
Two plus three make \printfive [last time I counted fingers].
```

What I want is: The first and second should print "Two plus three make 5." The third should print "Two plus three make 5 [last time I counted fingers]." In other words, I want the macro to notice whether or not it is immediately followed by `[` (without space), and behave differently.

Is this possible? I had no luck trying `\@ifnextchar`.

I use LuaLaTeX.

Possibly related: [Behavior of xparse and "token"-type argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142044/behavior-of-xparse-and-token-type-argument) which I do not quite grasp.

Comment: The answer is 'no': would that plus some explanation suffice?

Comment: There is ***no*** space after `\printfive` in the third case. You see one in the typescript, but it doesn't go through the input phase. As far as TeX is concerned, cases 2 and 3 are completely identical.

Comment: @JosephWright - I can take "no" for an answer. The `xparse` documentation does provide an explanation, but I was not sure if that was a feature that could be turned off somehow.

Comment: @egreg - Unfortunately, that means I cannot get what I seek.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules under which TeX reads input from a text file have the consequence that there is *no* space in

```
\foo [x]
```

The input is seven character long, but, as far as TeX is concerned, it is four *tokens*:

```
\foo•[•x•]
```

(here `•` is used for dividing tokens from each other, for expository purposes, and not part of what TeX “sees”). The space gets already ignored and discarded during the phase when the text input is transformed into tokens and there is no way to distinguish between the inputs

```
\foo[x]
\foo [x]
```

For all purposes they are perfectly equivalent. Well, barring devious tricks that are described in comments below, but that wouldn't help much in your situation.

You could trick TeX into “seeing” the space by saying `\obeyspaces` and then checking whether `\foo` is followed by an active space character (which wouldn't get ignored). However this has some consequences:

1. consecutive spaces in the input would be honored, so `a  b` would result in a double interword space between “a” and “b”;
2. spaces would not get ignored at the beginning of lines (no code indentation allowed).

Not really a feasible option, I guess you agree.

You could distinguish instead between

```
\printfive[last time I counted fingers]
```

and

```
\printfive-[last time I counted fingers]
```

by doing

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\printfive}{t-}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {Whatever you want to do if - follows}
    {\printfivewithoption}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\printfivewithoption}{O{default}}{%
  <whatever you want to do with #1>%
}
```

I can't recommend using `\DeclareDocumentCommand`, because this will override existing commands without warning.

Comment: That's all I need to know. My usage is in a very limited context (no code, so no code indentation problem). So, I may be able to use your solution. As for `\DeclareDocumentCommand` I am working with a limited number of packages, so over-writing existing macros is no problem. The main reason I use `\DeclareDocumentCommand` is that it gives my inner dictator a sense of power!

Comment: @RobtAll Try `\DeclareDocumentCommand{\box}{m}{whatever}` 

Comment: `\box` does not obey. Off with its head! 

Comment: It is _slightly_ misleading to say that `\foo [x]` and `\foo[x]` are completely equivalent: it is possible that `\foo` itself makes the space `\active`. Now, of course if this happens inside a macro argument, no change, but at top level in tex document, this is a change and will change output. `\def\foo{\catcode32\active}`, `{\catcode32\active\gdef {ZAZA}}`, `{\foo [X]}` vs `{\foo[X]}`. `\bye`

Comment: @jfbu Added a comment about “devious tricks”. `;-)`

Comment: @jfbu - Interesting TeX internal observation. But too dangerous for my usage.